# Ra's al Ghul story line

Tags: arrow, batman-begins

I'm curious about the storyline for Ra's al Ghul. In the end of Batman Begins, is he dead? But yet Ra's al Ghul appears in the Green Arrow. Them both being DC Comic story lines I'm curious how this is?

Comment: The movie *Batman Begins* and the TV show *Arrow* have nothing to do with each other. It's not the same Ra's al Ghul, the events of one didn't happen in the same universe as the events of the other.

Answer (score 3):

The Green Arrow and Batman Begins, whilst both being owned by DC, are separate commercial entities and exist in different continuities; the *Arrowverse* and the *Nolanverse*, respectively.

They share no overlapping Diegesis, and exist in separate narrative universes.

Comment: The OP's confusion is understandable, given the rising popularity of these "cinematic shared universes," but this answer is absolutely correct.  Nolan's Batman trilogy predates any effort to establish a DC shared universe among different media.  I'm not sure if Arrow and the other DC TV shows (shared among themselves) will be shared with the movies they're starting now.

Comment: It would certainly be nice if they could have come up with a different name.  That was really shoddy work on the writers' part to create that confusion, which I agree is quite easily understandable.

Comment: @JohnnyBones what do you mean, different name? they're both derivative of the same character from DC comics...

Comment: Wait.  Isn't that counter to the last sentence in your answer??

Comment: @JohnnyBones Late to the party here, but no, it doesn't. They may have different versions of the same characters, but their plotlines are otherwise completely different.